# EucDistance fails on last iteration of loop using ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, raster, arcgis-pro, distance, error-010240

I am building a tool for ArcGIS Pro 2.8.0 with Python using the [template](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/geoprocessing_and_python/a-template-for-python-toolboxes.htm) that ESRI provides. The first part of the tool defined in the execute function takes a point feature and loops through a search cursor to:

1. Create a viewshed for each individual point using the Radial Line of Sight Tool
2. Create a Euclidean distance raster for each individual point

The script runs as expected and outputs the viewshed and Euclidean distance features for every point until it gets to the last iteration of the loop where it gives the following error:

> ERROR 010240: Could not save raster dataset to
> C:\Users\rhuerta\Documents\ArcGIS\Projects\AP_Tool_Test\AP_Tool_Test.gdb\EucDist_thre1
> with output format FGDBR.

I've tried the solution suggested in [Saving rasters in a Python for loop fails only on last iteration](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/46897) , but I can't seem to get it to work.

Here is a sample of the part of the code that's failing:

```
 ## 1. Get the viewshed at 300ft radius (91.44 meters)
        ## in: point light feature, polygon park feature
        ## out: polygon feature reprsenting visible areas of the park fpr each point

        # Initiate search cursor
        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(AP_points, Carte_ID) as cursor:
            # Iterate through cursor and make a selection where Carte_ID = the current row
            for row in cursor:
                # arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute(AP_points, selection_type = 'NEW_SELECTION',
                #                             where_clause = f"{Carte_ID} = '{row[0]}'")
                
                c_id = str(row[0].split("-")[1])

                # Define the name of the output viewshed feature
                out_vs_fc = f'{out_name}_viewshed_{c_id}'
                
                # Define the name of the output field of view feature
                out_fov_fc = f'{out_name}_fov_{c_id}'
                
                # Define the name of the range radius feature
                out_range_radius_feature_class = f'{out_name}_range_radius_{c_id}'
                
                arcpy.AddMessage(f'creating field of view for lightpost with Carte ID {row[0]}...')
                
                # Run the radial line of sight tool
                arcpy.RadialLineOfSightAndRange_defense(arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute(AP_points, 
                                                                                                selection_type = 'NEW_SELECTION',
                                                                                                where_clause = f"{Carte_ID} = '{row[0]}'"), 
                                                                                                elev_raster, out_vs_fc, 
                                                                                                out_fov_fc, out_range_radius_feature_class,
                                                                                                4.26, 0, 91.44)

               
            ## 2. Calculate distance raster with the Euclidean distance tool
            ## Make sure to set processing extent to limits of park polygon in the environment
            
                # Set local variables
                inSourceData = arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(AP_points, "NEW_SELECTION", f"{Carte_ID} = '{row[0]}'")
                outData = f'euc_dist_ft_{c_id}'

                # Execute euclidean distance tool
                outEucDistance = EucDistance(inSourceData)

                arcpy.AddMessage(f'Created {outEucDistance}')

                # Save output
                outEucDistance.save(os.path.join(arcpy.env.workspace, outData))
               
                arcpy.AddMessage(f'Saved {os.path.join(arcpy.env.workspace, outData)}')

                outEucDistance = None
```

Comment: Have you tried executing the tools manually with the last inputs?

Comment: Hello, yes I was able to manually run the Euclidean distance tool on the final input. For some reason it only fails while on the final input of a loop...